# How to push in the middle of git merge, when too many files are to be merged

Tags: git, git-merge, git-push

After a long time, I updated my branch. 
I got over a hundred conflicts. 
I want to resolve to say 10 or 15 of them and then push it. (I will be doing it over several days).

Is there a way to commit/push when I have resolved only some of the files?

Comment: Possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4996809/how-to-commit-a-long-git-merge-in-the-middle-of-resolving-conflicts

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to commit/push when I have resolved only some of the files?

**No, you can do a partial commit.**

When you perform a merge and you have conflicts to resolve, git stores all the "non-conflicts" files in your `index` and once the conflicts are resolved it will commit your changes in the right order they were introduced.

What you wish to do it to "exclude" several files from the commits and this is not allowed.

#### What you can do instead?

- use `git cherry-pick` and grab small chunks of commits which will result in a smaller amount of conflicts.
- Open a new side branch and commit your file whenever you fixed any of them. It will leave your other files with conflicts but it will be easy to track them since they will have `<<<<<<` & `>>>>>>>>` in them so a simple search will reveal them.

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to push it onto the branch with unresolved conflicts.

But yes you could just push it to another branch on the remote.